# Манипулирование DOM в JavaScript работает не корректно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Снова столкнулся со странной проблемой, теперь связанной с `JavaScript`. Есть страница, на ней простенький `JavaScript`, также подключён `jQuery`.

```
function initTooltips() {
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.tt-trigger').each(function() {
        var index = $(this).data('tooltip');
        var pPos = $(this).position();
        var pWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        $('.tooltip.tt[data-tooltip="' + index + '"]').css({
        width: pWidth + 'px',
        top: (pPos.top + pHeight) + 'px',
        left: (pPos.left) + 'px' // pPos.left = 0, 150, 300 ..
        });
    });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.tt-trigger').each(function() {
        var index = $(this).data('tooltip');
        var pPos = $(this).position();
        var pWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        $('.tooltip.tt[data-tooltip="' + index + '"]').css({
        width: pWidth + 'px',
        top: (pPos.top + pHeight) + 'px',
        left: (pPos.left) + 'px'
        });
    });
});
};

$(function() {
    initTooltips();
});
```

Итак, код перестаёт работать (`$(this).position().left` начинает на все итерации выдавать `0`) в трёх ситуациях: если я выношу код из `load` и `resize` в отдельную функцию, если я выношу код за пределы `$(window).load()` (`document` не так уж и `ready`, видимо) или если я перехожу с этой страницы на какую-то другую, а затем возвращаюсь кнопкой браузера "Назад" (начинает работать после обновления страницы).
Например, такой код уже не работает (но ошибок в консоль не выдаёт, просто все нужные переменные равны нулю):

```
function foo() {
    $('.tt-trigger').each(function() {
        var index = $(this).data('tooltip');
        var pPos = $(this).position();
        var pWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        var pHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

        $('.tooltip.tt[data-tooltip="' + index + '"]').css({
        width: pWidth + 'px',
        top: (pPos.top + pHeight) + 'px',
        left: (pPos.left) + 'px' // pPos.left = 0, 0, 0 ..
        });
    });
};
function initTooltips() {
    $(window).load( foo() );
    $(window).resize( foo() );
};

$(function() {
    initTooltips();
});
```

То есть поведение очень странное, но я не вижу причин для этого. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы показали код, который работает? Очень хорошо. Теперь покажите, пожалуйста, код, который не работает.

Comment: Проблема с кнопкой "Назад" присутствует из-за того, что код на JavaScript отрабатывает до компиляции less (через less.js). Соответственно, при подключении заранее подготовленного CSS проблема исчезает, поэтому в продакшене её не будет. Впрочем, я всё равно не понимаю, почему Chrome так странно интерпретирует JavaScript при нажатии кнопки "Назад".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, это другое дело.

Вы совершенно правильно поместили одинаковый повторяемый код в отдельную функцию. Но теперь Вам надо не вызывать Ваш обработчик, a передавать ссылку на него:

```
function initTooltips() {
    $(window).load( foo );
    $(window).resize( foo );
};
```